# Why doesn't the js file work in another folder?

Tags: html, directory

My folder hierarchy is:

```
\- htdocs
    |- folder
        |- bootstrap
            |- js
                |- boostrap.min.js
        |- index.html
```

I'm using this script to call  the .js file:

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also I've tried:

```
<script src="folder/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I had no success, does anybody here know how it works?

Edit: When I said "it doesn't work", I mean that the js file is not loaded.
My log file:

> 1 - - [16/Nov/2012:15:16:21 -0300] "GET /bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1310 "localhost/THU/index.html"; "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0

Comment: are you using a rewrite engine?

Comment: Are you running this straight from your disk or on a Web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your folder structure, and so long as this `<script>` is in `index.html` that you call out, your first import is correct:

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

p.s. - Don't forget to include `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?  Have you checked your server's access log file?

Comment: Edited explaning about the "doesn't work". My log file: ::1 - - [16/Nov/2012:15:16:21 -0300] "GET /bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1310 "http://localhost/THU/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0"

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` is not needed in HTML 5.

Comment: @ChrisPeters Show me where it says this is HTML 5

Comment: @Doon That's a request for a CSS file, not a JS file. But it still offers a clue - the request is coming in relative to your document root (note the `/` at the start).  Given your folder diagram, it doesn't appear that your `bootstrap` folder is in your doc root folder.

Answer (score 1):

Open the page in Chrome. Right click > View Source. Right click the js reference and open in new tab. That will show you where the browser thinks you're pointing it to and you should be able to adjust from there.

Comment: Strange, I've just done it and it seems the .js file is correct. But the JS file in not being loaded. 
I added the type as Madbreakes said:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Okay, you may want to change your question then and define why you think it's not working. It could be the js in page is actually screwed up and not the reference at all.

Comment: Thank you Rick Calder. It is not working because the page looks like a normal HTML page, the form and the content is not being loaded with the bootstrap style.

Comment: And yet another down vote without reason. The answer gives him the knowledge to troubleshoot his problem and find a solution.